# How to format API response

Tags: reactjs, api, format, response

I'm writing a react app that fetches data from a DynamoDB table using a Lambda function. The function successfully retrieves an array of objects as shown below. I've tested this in the AWS console and in Postman.

```js
[
  {
    "Obj1Key1": {
      "S": "Obj1Value1"
    },
    "Obj1Key2": {
      "S": "Obj1Value2"
    },
    "Obj1Key3": {
      "S": "Obj1Value3"
    },
    "Obj1Key4": {
      "S": "Obj1Value4"
    }
  },
    {
    "Obj2Key1": {
      "S": "Obj2Value1"
    },
    "Obj2Key2": {
      "S": "Obj2Value2"
    },
    "Obj2Key3": {
      "S": "Obj2Value3"
    },
    "Obj2Key4": {
      "S": "Obj2Value4"
    }
  },
      {
    "Obj3Key1": {
      "S": "Obj3Value1"
    },
    "Obj3Key2": {
      "S": "Obj3Value2"
    },
    "Obj3Key3": {
      "S": "Obj3Value3"
    },
    "Obj3Key4": {
      "S": "Obj3Value4"
    }
  }
]
```

..and below is the function in the React app that gets the data:

```js
 ...
 ...
 const [ response , setResponse ]  = useState();
 ...
 
 async function fetchData() {
    try {
      const body = JSON.stringify({
        etc....
      });

      await fetch("https://url..etc", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: body 
      }).then(res => setResponse(res))
      
   } catch (error) {
     console.log(error);
   }
 };
```

However When I get the raw response from the React app, and I console log it, my console shows the following
[image]

How can I get the array of objects from this response? I tried different combinations of parsing and stringifying but was not able to get the array as an array. Adding .then(res => res.text()). before .then(res => setResponse(res)) gets me the response I'm looking for but as a string. I need to get it as an array.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try to console log for `response.body`?

Comment: have you tried to get `response.json()` instead of `.text()`?

Comment: @DreamBold I tried, got the error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'body')

Comment: Then you're not sending the api request correctly, I guess

Comment: @leo When I do that, I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'o', "[object Obj"... is not valid JSON

Comment: I can see `body` in your attached pic

Comment: Try ` .then(res => setResponse(JSON.stringify(res.data)))`